# Chrome page is not navigation after search page, using chrome driver, selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a script which opens pepperfry.com , searches for clocks and sorts them in price low to high.The aim is to verify the first 8 items are sorted in price. But after the sorting operation, we get two pop up windows about discount and account creation. I am not able to navigate to the pop ups to close them as the whole page is hanging and the script execution is not proceeding at all. Please help on what I am doing wrong.

I have tried popup , `alerts`, normal `webdriver wait` operations. Nothing helped.

Script:

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;

public class PepperFry {
    WebDriver driver;
    XSSFSheet sheet;
    XSSFWorkbook WB;
    XSSFRow row;
    FileInputStream Fis;
    FileOutputStream Fos;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void beforeSuite() throws IOException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "resource\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

    @Test
    public void Searchsort() throws IOException {
        driver.get("https://www.pepperfry.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='search']")).sendKeys(Keys.chord("Clocks", Keys.ENTER));
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='curSortType']")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='sortBY']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Price: Low to High')]")).click(); // Hangs after this point
        //driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
        //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.popup-close")).click();

    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void afterSuite() {
        driver.close();
    }

}
```

[image: Pic of page after sort operation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line no need of it, if you trying to sort elements low to high price -

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='sortBY']")).click();
```

it is clicking random sort type in the dropdown.

.....................................................................................................................................

I must say it was nice challenge to handle 2 popups at a time and which one to deal with first?.

Here is the solution - First thing to notice is the popups are not displayed when you roam manually without searching on the page so has to perform some action.
second thing is login popup will not be displayed when you do it manually.

To handle the popup(discount popup in blue color) which is generated by some javascript/ajax code at run time
you need to switch to frame because it is inside frame. And it will not go away with simple `driver.switchTo.frame()` you have to use explicit wait as -

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions
                .frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='notification-frame-~1971576c6']")));
```

after switching to frame you are ready to close it -

```
WebElement size = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("close")));
```

while performing above actions the login popup will appear and it will appear before closing the discount popup or after closing the popup(not fix) and hence the above popup closing is handled using explicit wait.

Now to handle the login popup  use explicit wait again because the popup appears earlier or delayed every time varies  -

```
WebElement closebutton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//div[@id='signinupPopupBox']/a")));
        closebutton.click();
```

Here is complete working code -

```
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.pepperfry.com/");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='search']")).sendKeys(Keys.chord("Clocks", Keys.ENTER));

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions
                .frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@name='notification-frame-~1971576c6']")));
        WebElement size = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.className("close")));

        size.click();
        WebElement closebutton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(".//div[@id='signinupPopupBox']/a")));
        closebutton.click();
        // select default content after closing the iframe popup
        //driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='curSortType']")).click();

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions
                .elementToBeClickable((By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Price: Low to High')]")))).click();
        System.out.println("script end");
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like after search, if you wait some times then you are getting that builder. so go for wait after search and close it

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='search']")).sendKeys(Keys.chord("Clocks", Keys.ENTER));

    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#signinupPopupBox a.popup-close")));
```